# WordPress: How to Sort Post list custom column - multi deep level custom meta?

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin, meta-query

meta key is `test`, however it's an object.

Example:

```php
$data = get_post_meta($post_id, "test", true);
echo $data["a"];
echo $data["b"];
echo $data["c"];
```

## Question:

- How to sort data by custom meta (in object form) in WordPress post list.
- I'd like to sort `A`, `B` and `C` columns.

[image: ref]

Ref: [wp_meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

---

```php
<!-- Post Editor | custom field in MetaBox -->
<input name="test[a]" />
<input name="test[b]" />
<input name="test[c]" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

```php
add_filter("manage_customPost_posts_columns", function($col) {
    $col["a"] = "A";
    $col["b"] = "B";
    $col["c"] = "C";
    return $col;
});

//________________________________________________________

add_filter("manage_edit-customPost_sortable_columns", function($col) {
    $col["a"] = "a";
    $col["b"] = "b";
    $col["b"] = "c";
    return $col;
});

//________________________________________________________

add_action("pre_get_posts", function($query) {
    $orderby = $query->get("orderby");

        // ▼▼▼ Issue start from here ▼▼▼
        $meta_query = array(
            "key" => "test[".$orderby."]",
        );
        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
        $query->set("orderby", "value");
        // ▲▲▲ Issue end from here ▲▲▲

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So **pre_get_posts** filters a [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object which means anything you could do via `query_posts()` you can do via `$query->set()` and `$query->get()`. In particular we can make use of the meta_query attribute (see [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)):

```php
//Get original meta query
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

//Add our meta query to the original meta queries
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'=>'featured',
    'value'=>'yes',
    'compare'=>'!=',
);
$query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
```